# Cannot find symbol error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

I'm trying to add fragments to a navigation drawer. But I have the error: cannot find symbol class Fragment.

I added: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Also add the fragment object(Fragment fragment)

Where is the mistake?
What should I do?

Home.java

```
package com.example.eatit;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        /* Handle navigation view item clicks here. */
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

build.grandle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eatit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

    def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha06"

    // Java
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

I've tried to search the web and forums but so far I didn't find anything helpful.

Thank You so much.

Comment: post Fragment class or code of adding Fragment also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are importing `Fragment` from the old Android Support library (`android.support.v<x>`) while you’ve configured your project to use AndroidX, so make sure you are importing and using the correct library.

Please visit [this link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to find the correct import for `Fragment`.

> Replace `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much !

 I did build the app, there is no error but still I have the red font on 
'nav_home'/'nav_home'.... 

and the message is Cannot resolve symbol 'nav_home'

Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: again its the same error. please check the link i attached

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
import androidx.core.app.Fragment;
import androidx.core.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.core.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

to:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary

**update:** you must update to androidx automatically by refactor and after that some will don't update automatically, need to do it manually(copy,past), more information: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your Build.gradle file:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:{latest_version}"
```

Example:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
```

Answer (score 0):

### 2021 ?

I'm no gradle expert but this seems to help

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4"
```

Seemingly needed for `FragmentContainerView` for example?